# How to Prevent Foreground Service from Stopping on Clear All from Recent Apps on MI, Redmi, Xiaomi Devices?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile-development, foreground-service

When [tag:Foreground Service] is running and User taps on Clear all from recent Apps then it is stopping the service.It's happening only in specific devices Such as MI, Redmi, Xiaomi etc.

I couldn't found the it's solution.
I want to prevent the service from Stopping even if user taps `clear all` from recent task.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Having foreground service running should in theory prevent app process from being killed when it's swiped (or clear all-ed) in recents. But that's just theory and some manufacturers direspect it to "improve battery life". IIRC your app needs to bo added to battery usage whitelist (and allowed to autostart?) in order to survive those optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

The service can not running forever. You can suggest to user exclude your app from [battery optimization](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS) and [allow autostart](https://github.com/judemanutd/AutoStarter). In such case you can use `WorkManager` with foreground request to do long running operations when app is not running and can be started from background (depends from other permissions like location and etc).

The other options is suggest to user hold app in recently list. Some of launcher from vendors provide feature with "hold/lock" button. So when user click `clear all`, app that hold have to stayed.